# How to get the date of an item (IVssItem) in SourceSafe?

Tags: com, visual-sourcesafe, sourcesafe-6.0

## Short Version

i am trying to figure out how to get the **Date** of an item. The date i'm interested in is the **Date** that appears in the SourceSafe user interface:

[image]

In this example, the date is **6/9/2020 11:49 am**

## Long Version

Using the Microsoft Visual SouceSafe COM API, you have access to an [`IVssItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/7k84wz1s(v=vs.80)):

```
//InterfaceID: {2A0DE0EA-2E9F-11D0-9236-00AA00A1EB95}
public interface IVSSItem
{
   public string Spec { get; set; }
   public Boolean Binary { get; set; }
   public Boolean Deleted { get; set; }
   public VSSItemType Type { get; }
   public String LocalSpec { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public IVSSItem Parent { get; }
   public Int32 VersionNumber { get; }
   public IVSSItems Items(Boolean IncludeDeleted) { get; }
   public void Get(ref String Local; VSSFlags iFlags);
   public void Checkout(String Comment, String Local, VSSFlags iFlags);     
   public void Checkin(String Comment, String Local, VSSFlags iFlags);
   public UndoCheckout(String Local, VSSFlags iFlags);
   public VSSFileStatus IsCheckedOut { get; }
   public IVSSCheckouts Checkouts { get; }
   public Boolean IsDifferent(String Local) { get; }
   public IVSSItem Add(String Local, String Comment, VSSFlags iFlags);
   public IVSSItem NewSubproject(String Name, String Comment);
   public void Share(IVSSItem pIItem: IVSSItem, String Comment, VSSFlags iFlags);
   public void Destroy();
   public void Move(IVSSItem pINewParent);
   public void Label(String Label, String Comment);
   public IVSSVersions Versions(VSSFlags iFlags) { get; }
   public IVSSItem Version(VARIANT Version) { get; }
   public IVSSItems Links { get; }
   public IVSSItem Branch(String Comment, VSSFlags iFlags);
}
```

The issue is that i don't see any way to access that **Date** that can be seen in the SourceSafe user interface.

## Research

[Johannnes Knaupp asked the same question in 2001.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vstudio.sourcesafe/sZMqyQBXWZ8) In that thread, some suggested that the way to find the date of an item is to look at the date of the last **IVssVersion**.

`IVSSVersion` **does** indeed have a date:

```
//InterfaceID {783CD4E8-9D54-11CF-B8EE-00608CC9A71F}
public interface IVSSVersion
{
   String Username { get; }
   Int32 VersionNumber { get; }
   String Action { get; }
   DateTime Date { get; }  <--------------------
   String Comment { get; }
   String Label { get; }
   String IVSSItem VSSItem { get; }
}
```

Unfortunately:

- that's not the date of the file
- that's the date the action was taken

This can even be seen in the SourceSafe user interface:

[image]

And it can be confirmed through the API.

Johannes noted this back in 2001:

> These dates are not the same:
>
> A file created at 10:05 may be checked in at 10:08.

What's more is that `IVssVersion.Date` doesn't represent a change to the file. It represents some *action* was taken:

- “Added"
- “Archived"
- “Archived versions of"
- “Branched at version"
- “Checked in"
- “Created"
- “Deleted"
- “Destroyed"
- “Labeled"
- “Moved from"
- “Moved to"
- “Pinned to version"
- “Purged"
- “Recovered"
- “Renamed to"
- “Restored"
- “Rollback to version"
- “Shared"
- “Unpinned"

Even worse:

- if i **Added** a file from `6/19/1999` *today*
- the **Date** of action will be *"today"*
- rather than `6/19/1999`

So the question is:

- How to do it?
- How to read the `DateTime` of a file?
- How does the SourceSafe user interface do it?